# SendInput vs. keybd_event

Tags: delphi, keyboard-events, sendinput

MSDN states that keybd_event has been superceded by SendInput. During a rewrite I switched to using SendInput...which was fine **except** when trying to send an Alt-key combination. On a Win7 64-bit system (haven't tried elsewhere yet), send an Alt-key causes a long delay before the keystroke is apparent in the target application.

Any ideas why? Or what I've done wrong? For now, I've gone back to keybd_event--the second version below.

```
//Keyboard input from this version appears only after a ~4-5 second
//time lag...
procedure SendAltM;
var
  KeyInputs: array of TInput;
  KeyInputCount: Integer;
  //--------------------------------------------
  procedure KeybdInput(VKey: Byte; Flags: DWORD);
  begin
    Inc(KeyInputCount);
    SetLength(KeyInputs, KeyInputCount);
    KeyInputs[KeyInputCount - 1].Itype := INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    with  KeyInputs[KeyInputCount - 1].ki do
    begin
      wVk := VKey;
      wScan := MapVirtualKey(wVk, 0);
      dwFlags := KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY;
      dwFlags := Flags or dwFlags;
      time := 0;
      dwExtraInfo := 0;
    end;
  end;
begin
  KeybdInput(VK_MENU, 0);                 // Alt
  KeybdInput(Ord('M'), 0);                 
  KeybdInput(Ord('M'), KEYEVENTF_KEYUP);   
  KeybdInput(VK_MENU, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP);   // Alt
  SendInput(KeyInputCount, KeyInputs[0], SizeOf(KeyInputs[0]));
end;


//Keyboard input from this version appears immediately...
procedure SendAltM;
begin
  keybd_event( VK_MENU, MapVirtualkey( VK_MENU, 0 ), 0, 0);
  keybd_event( Ord('M'), MapVirtualKey( Ord('M'),0), 0, 0);
  keybd_event( Ord('M'), MapVirtualKey( Ord('M'),0), KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
  keybd_event( VK_MENU, MapVirtualkey( VK_MENU, 0 ), KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
end;
```

Comment: This big problem with `keybd_event` is that your events may get spliced with real ones. So `SendInput` is the job. No idea why you are having problems. Yet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Problem 1**

You did not initialise `KeyInputCount`. So its value is undefined. Set it to zero before calling `KeybdInput` the first time. Or just get rid of it and use `Length(KeyInputs)` instead.

**Problem 2**

Your setting of `dwFlags` is incorrect. Don't include `KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY`. You did not include it in the code that calls `keybd_event`, and you should not include it for `SendInput`.

**Corrected code**

This version works.

```
procedure SendAltM;
var
  KeyInputs: array of TInput;
  //--------------------------------------------
  procedure KeybdInput(VKey: Byte; Flags: DWORD);
  begin
    SetLength(KeyInputs, Length(KeyInputs)+1);
    KeyInputs[high(KeyInputs)].Itype := INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    with  KeyInputs[high(KeyInputs)].ki do
    begin
      wVk := VKey;
      wScan := MapVirtualKey(wVk, 0);
      dwFlags := Flags;
    end;
  end;
begin
  KeybdInput(VK_MENU, 0);                 // Alt
  KeybdInput(Ord('M'), 0);
  KeybdInput(Ord('M'), KEYEVENTF_KEYUP);
  KeybdInput(VK_MENU, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP);   // Alt
  SendInput(Length(KeyInputs), KeyInputs[0], SizeOf(KeyInputs[0]));
end;
```

Comment: The uninitialized count would explain the delay. The OS would take who-knows-how-long processing all the bogus null mouse events in the array before finally getting to the four valid keyboard events at the end.

Comment: @Rob The main problem is the erroneous flag I think.

Comment: Thanks David and @Rob. I don't know whether the uninitialized KeyInputCount or the flag was the problem; just glad to get this figured out. Oh, and it's so easy to see that KeyInputCount was uninitialized...now that someone else has pointed it out!

Answer (score 3):

this way you can use the `keybd_event`:

```
keybd_event( VK_MENU, MapVirtualkey( VK_MENU, 0 ), KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY or 0, 0);
  keybd_event( Ord('M'), MapVirtualKey( Ord('M'),0), KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY or 0, 0);
  keybd_event( Ord('M'), MapVirtualKey( Ord('M'),0), KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY or KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
  keybd_event( VK_MENU, MapVirtualkey( VK_MENU, 0 ), KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY or KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
```