# How to get keyboard keys and key combinations?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

My task is to create a remote keyboard, something like the TeamViewer keyboard.

Ok, i have two apps:

- First one is server that accepts connections(socket) and listen for commands.
- Second one is the client app that sends keyword commands to the server.

> For example: If i have a session and hit the windows key, this key has
>   to be sent and server has to receive the key and than has to hit it. 
>   Like i'm working on the server.

Please give an example.

Comment: Server side will install a keyboard hook and the client side will `SendInput`.

Comment: Thanks. Can you give me an example for the server ? When server receive the command, how to execute this command ?
At the moment i can send key code to server, but i don't know how to activate this code on the server machine.

Comment: Call [`SendInput`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I'm sure there will be many examples around.

Answer (score 0):

Use a keyboard hook

Click here for an example:

http://delphi.about.com/od/windowsshellapi/a/delphi-hooks.htm

When you want to execute the shortcut remote use `SendIndput` read this for an example of how to use: [SendInput vs. keybd_event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18662637/sendinput-vs-keybd-event)

Comment: Please don't advise the use of `keybd_event`.

Comment: I've updated my answer David. But thank you for letting me know.