# Why should I use SendInput over mouse and keybd events?

Tags: python, mouseevent, ctypes, keyboard-events, sendinput

When looking up how to use [keybd_event on Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-keybd_event), it says:

> Note  This function has been superseded. Use [SendInput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput) instead.

But when looking at [how to use SendInput](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62189991/how-to-wrap-the-sendinput-function-to-python-using-ctypes), it looks a lot more complex for not much, if any, gain, even though it can handle mouse and keyboard similarly.

For instance: Pressing Ctrl down with minimal effort:

keybd_event:

> windll.user32.keybd_event(0x11, 0, 0, 0)

sendInput takes 6 more lines while also calling a very similar-looking function, KEYBDINPUT:

> lib = WinDLL('user32')
> lib.SendInput.argtypes = w.UINT,POINTER(INPUT),c_int
> lib.SendInput.restype = w.UINT
>
> i = INPUT()
> i.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD
> i.ki = KEYBDINPUT(0,0x11,0,0,0)
> lib.SendInput(1,byref(i),sizeof(INPUT))

Comment: Why?  Because the documentation says so.  The "why" isn't really on-topic for an SO question.  Ask Microsoft :^).  For calling `SendInput` See [How to wrap the SendInput function to python using ctypes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62189991/235698)

Comment: @MarkTolonen - Oh, right, the high scoring "What is a serialVersionUID and why should I use it?" and other "Why should I use" are really old, I missed that detail.

Comment: That question's answer answered the "what".  The "why" was in the documentation just as your question was.  The old API exists if you find it simpler, but risks deprecation and removal someday since it is superseded.

Comment: SendInput docs: The SendInput function inserts the events in the INPUT structures serially into the keyboard or mouse input stream. These events are not interspersed with other keyboard or mouse input events inserted either by the user (with the keyboard or mouse) or by calls to keybd_event, mouse_event, or other calls to SendInput.

Comment: @MarkTolonen - Thanks! ... Gonna try and memorize that! I read it and forgot... And since this question is bad... Gonna ask for a deletion... Or not, since that wouldn't help?

Answer (score 0):

As a comment on [SendInput vs. keybd_event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18662637/sendinput-vs-keybd-event) says, emphasis mine:

> **This big problem with keybd_event is that your events may get spliced with real ones. So SendInput is the job.** No idea why you are having problems. Yet.
> –
> [David Heffernan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/505088/david-heffernan)
> Sep 6, 2013 at 16:50